# How to post in json as backend?

Tags: python, json, fastapi

my question is how do I post the output using json as backend?
just need to post translate text
my backend coding

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Depends, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from googletrans import Translator
import uvicorn

#connect to translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'])

app = FastAPI(debug=True)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="template")

@app.get("/")
async def home(request: Request):
    return ('index.html',{'request': request})


@app.post("/")
async def trans(request: Request):
    text = request.get('Input_text')
    lang = request.get('lang_select')

    # detect language text
    #dt = translator.detect(text)
    # detect input language
    #dt2 = dt.lang

    # translate the text
    translated = translator.translate(text,lang)
    out_text = translated.text
    pronouce = out_text.pronunciation

#transData={'request': request ,'text_translate': out_text,'text_pronouce':pronouce}

    return ({'request': request ,'text_translate': out_text,'text_pronouce':pronouce})

if __name__=="__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app,host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```

and json format to post the output

```
{
"text_translate": "out_text"
"text_pronouce":"pronouce"
}
```

clearly, my post-return make this code not function properly.
Any help  or solution is appreciated...stuck for days now

Comment: What is the return you get now?

Comment: where do you call this POST method?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe sorry now edited it with full coding, post and get method is use in html and fast api already cover with app.get and app.post as method value...still get that error tho "ValueError: [TypeError("'re.Pattern' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the response with `jsonable_encoder` and then return the data with `JSONResponse`

Code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Depends, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from googletrans import Translator
import uvicorn

#connect to translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'])

app = FastAPI(debug=True)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="template")

@app.get("/")
async def home(request: Request):
    return ('index.html',{'request': request})


@app.post("/")
async def trans(request: Request):
    text = request.get('Input_text')
    lang = request.get('lang_select')

    # detect language text
    #dt = translator.detect(text)
    # detect input language
    #dt2 = dt.lang

    # translate the text
    translated = translator.translate(text,lang)
    out_text = translated.text
    pronouce = out_text.pronunciation

#transData={'request': request ,'text_translate': out_text,'text_pronouce':pronouce}
    data = jsonable_encoder({'text_translate': out_text,'text_pronouce':pronouce})
    return JSONResponse(content=data)

if __name__=="__main__":
   uvicorn.run(app,host="127.0.0.1",port=8000)
```